# Tesseract OCR: Parsing table cells

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I am using Tesseract-OCR v4.0.0 (alpha?) from cmd to extract text from a png of a table shown below:

[image: Image of the input data (png)]

I wanted Tesseract-OCR to parse what was in one cell before moving on to the next. I do not want to move on to the next word in the 'line'.

**Expected:**

`. . . John Smith 07 March,2017 Chicago Milwaukee Detroit Pacific Ocean . . .`

**Actual**:

`. . . John Smith 07 March,2017 Chicago Pacific Ocean Milwaukee Detroit . . .`

**I have tried:**

- Changing page segmentation with --psm flag, from 0-13. Results are either usually the same with minor differences or unreadable.

Is there any other way to configure Tesseract to read all the contents of one cell before moving on to the next? Else, are there any workarounds?

Comment: might wanna check my post out with the answer, and yes `--psm 6` usually does the trick?

Answer (score 2):

I spend sometimes answering this question I saw few people asking the same question.

The solution I used here is to use Opencv to pre process the image before using tesseract. After that some arrangement is needed.
Sorry My code is quit long I think some can make it shorter. But anyway it get the job done.
I couldn't explain the code line by line but I added comments hope it can give a general idea about what is going on.

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np
import pytesseract 
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract"
```

**reading Image and filtring**

```
table = cv2.imread("Table.png")
# adding some Border around image 
table= cv2.copyMakeBorder(table,20,20,20,20,cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,value=[255,255,255])
```

## Removing noise from image

```
table_c = cv2.GaussianBlur(cv2.cvtColor(table,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY),(3,3),0,0)
# Threshold
_,thre = cv2.threshold(table_c,200,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

## Geting rows only in the image

```
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT,(100,1))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thre,cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,kernel)
contours,h = cv2.findContours(morph, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
rows = [None]*len(contours)
for i, c in enumerate(contours):
    rows[i] = cv2.boundingRect(cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 3, True))
rows = sorted(rows, key=lambda b:b[1], reverse=False)
```

## Geting cols only in the image

```
kernel2 = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT,(1,50))
morph2 = cv2.morphologyEx(thre,cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,kernel2)
contours,h = cv2.findContours(morph2, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
table = cv2.drawContours(table, contours, 0, (0,255,0), 3)

cols = [None]*len(contours)
for i, c in enumerate(contours):
    cols[i] = cv2.boundingRect(cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 3, True))
cols = sorted(cols, key=lambda b:b[0], reverse=False)
```

## removing rows and cols and keep text only

```
_,thre2 = cv2.threshold(thre,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
no_table = cv2.bitwise_and(morph,thre2)
no_table = cv2.bitwise_and(morph2,no_table)

kernel2 = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT,(10,2))
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(no_table,cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,kernel2)
```

## get each text in a box

```
contours,h = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours_poly = [None]*len(contours)
boundRect = [None]*len(contours)
for i, c in enumerate(contours):
    contours_poly[i] = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 3, True)
    boundRect[i] = cv2.boundingRect(contours_poly[i])
#     cv2.rectangle(table, (int(boundRect[i][0]), int(boundRect[i][1])),
#                  (int(boundRect[i][0]+boundRect[i][2]), int(boundRect[i][1]+boundRect[i][3])), (0,0,255), 2)
# table = cv2.drawContours(table, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
```

## Crop each box and recognise text

## get the row and the cols of each text and it's position in the image

```
text_position = []
offest = 10
boundingBoxes = sorted(boundRect, key=lambda b:b[0], reverse=False)


for rect in boundingBoxes:
    if rect[2] > 30 and rect[3]>10:
        image = table[rect[1]-offest:rect[1]+rect[3]+offest,rect[0]-offest:rect[0]+rect[2]+offest]
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image)
        for i,row in enumerate(rows):
            if i < len(rows):
                if rect[1] >row[1] and rect[1] <rows[i+1][1]:
                    r = i 
                    break 
        for i,col in enumerate(cols):
            if i < len(cols):
                if rect[0] >col[0] and rect[0] <cols[i+1][0]:
                    c = i 
                    break
                    
        text_position.append({'Text':text.split("\n")[0],"row":r,'col':c,"X":rect[0],"Y":rect[1]})
```

## combined text in the same row and cols

```
indexs = []
for j,t in enumerate(text_position):
    list_re = []
    for i,tt in enumerate(text_position):
        if tt["row"] == t["row"] and tt["col"] == t["col"] :
            list_re.append(i)
    if len(list_re)>1:
        indexs.append(list_re)
        
indexs = list(set(tuple(i) for i in indexs))
text = ""
for indexs_ in indexs:
    text_repeated = [text_position[i] for i in indexs_]
    text_repeated = sorted(text_repeated, key=lambda b:b["Y"], reverse=False)
    for i in range(len(text_repeated)):
        text += text_repeated[i]["Text"]+" "
    new_dic = {'Text': text, 'row':text_repeated[0]["row"] , 'col': text_repeated[0]["col"], 'X': text_repeated[0]["X"], 'Y': text_repeated[-1]["Y"]}
    for i in indexs_:
        text_position.pop(i)
    text_position.append(new_dic)
```

Final Output will be a list of dictionaries each contains text, row, and col of each cell in the table like below

```
[{'Text': 'Jane Doe', 'row': 3, 'col': 1, 'X': 67, 'Y': 167},
 {'Text': 'John Smith', 'row': 2, 'col': 1, 'X': 67, 'Y': 86},
 {'Text': 'Name', 'row': 1, 'col': 1, 'X': 68, 'Y': 59},
 {'Text': '07 March, 2017', 'row': 3, 'col': 2, 'X': 301, 'Y': 167},
 {'Text': '07 March, 2017', 'row': 2, 'col': 2, 'X': 301, 'Y': 86},
 {'Text': ' ', 'row': 1, 'col': 2, 'X': 302, 'Y': 59},
 {'Text': 'Los Angeles', 'row': 3, 'col': 3, 'X': 536, 'Y': 167},
 {'Text': 'Detroit', 'row': 2, 'col': 3, 'X': 536, 'Y': 140},
 {'Text': 'Locations', 'row': 1, 'col': 3, 'X': 536, 'Y': 58},
 {'Text': 'Currently in', 'row': 1, 'col': 4, 'X': 769, 'Y': 58},
 {'Text': 'Pacific Ocean', 'row': 2, 'col': 4, 'X': 770, 'Y': 85},
 {'Text': 'Chicago Milwaukee Detroit ',
  'row': 2,
  'col': 3,
  'X': 535,
  'Y': 140}
```